# End line with "..." in CSS

Tags: css

I would like to know the property that I can use to make the interrupted sentences (by width) end with ..., for example:

```
div { width: 100px;
unknown-property: ...;
```

}

```
<div>That is my sentence under 100px </div>
```

and if the sentence exceeds 100px, that is what happens:

```
That is my sentence with more...
```

I hope I could explain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

And you may need:

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: Elementary, dear Watson. Thats all I needed. I couldn't remember the word "Ellipsis" and that's pretty sad :( lol, thank you

Comment: acctualy it did not work on http://www.transmaqequipamentos.com.br/ if ou could pls take a look , I set these properties to ultimos ul li h3 a